# Graphviz edge between nodes wrong drawn

Tags: graphviz, edges

graphivz shows a strange behavior for the generation of a graph. The connection between node 5 to 6 goes from 5.south to 6.east, but I want 5.west to 6.north. Furthermore, from 7.west to 16.north, the 16.north position is not centered. What I am doing wrong?
[edges are wrong drawn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rkuM.png)

On the other hand the generated graph with the website https://graphs.grevian.org looks good and fulfill all my requirements.
[edges are correct drawn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9eVi.png)

Here is the code example which was used for the generation of both pictures:

```
digraph G {
pencolor=transparent;
graph [splines=ortho];
subgraph cluster1 {
1->2->3->4->5;
}
subgraph cluster2 {
6->7->8->9->10.1;
}
subgraph cluster3 {
11->12->13->14->15;
}
subgraph cluster4 {
16->17->18->19->20;
}
subgraph cluster5 {
21->22->23->24->25
}
1->11;
3->21;
5->6;
1 [label="1-1"];
7->16;
}
```

On my system ubuntu 18.04.03 LTS is graphviz 2.40.1-2 installed. In the terminal I use

```
dot -Tpng graph_G.dot -o graph_G.png
```

Comment: Ortho splines are extremely hard to tune. Once you experience a problem with them it's almost impossible to make graphviz change it's mind about how to draw them. I don't recommend you using them. You may achieve the same square edges with regular splines. It's a bit cumbersome in the source, but much more reliable than ortho splines, see my reply to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55402109/can-dot-produce-a-more-structured-graph/55403592

Comment: Thank you for your advice. The idea works fine for single nodes that are connected by regular splines. The adaption of the method with regular spline resulted in my case to clusters (e.g. 1->2->3->4->5) which are not longer in the same horizontal line. Therefore, it is not helpful for me.