# graphviz how to draw a vertical tree like file managers do

Tags: graphviz, pygraphviz

How do I render a vertical tree image like file manager do. By default graphviz is rendering a triangular tree. The problem is if the width of a level (rank) is too many, the produced image is too wide. Typically file manager applications model a directory hierarchy on the vertical axioms.

specific example, given a family tree with 5 brothers, each having 5 kids, would require rendering of 25 nodes ... which becomes too wide.

Here is  an example image

[image]

Update: ... thanks everyone, I have managed to make some progress. But I am seeing some weird edges as marked on the picture below. It looks good at the first couple of tiers, then it gets bad.

[image]

Comment: Can you include an image that shows (in general) what your goal is?

Comment: See possible way to go in my answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55402109/can-dot-produce-a-more-structured-graph/55403592#55403592

Comment: Can you add the **dot** code you used?

Comment: I am using python graphviz package, the produced .dot file is ... I hate "stack overflow comments" ... it is 2020 for pete's sake. what is with mini-markdown. I will try to figure out how to attach a file.

Comment: The dot contains some non-English (UTF-8) names (as seen by the picture). The resultant DOT is too large to paste here. The python code is only 133 lines, so I paste the relevant portion here.

Comment: Sorry I can not figure out how to add code. I have tried single back quote, indent by 4 spaces and ctl-k to no avail.

Comment: @MediMontaseri you should be aware that some of those people that try to answer questions like do not know the python graphviz package but look at the problem from a pure graphviz point of view thats why they ask for the dot file. Personally if the dot version was available I could try play around with it on http://viz-js.com/

Comment: @jens I understand your valid comment. I was just getting a bit frustrated with the how-to add the DOT file. I tried pasting it, it said it is too large, then I thought I will put the python code and I am still wrestling with how-to add some comments on this board.  I guess, my next move would be to generate a smaller DOT file. Do you have any tips on how to add pre-formatted content like code . the single back quote is not working for me, the ctl-k is not working for me ... etc

Comment: @MediMontaseri to add more than a few line of code i ususal copy it notepad++ first, mark it all and hit tab to indent to insert a tab on every line alternative use block mark to insert spaces at start of all lines simultaniously. I have not have the problem with to text for code (did you try to add it as a comment? the edit your question instead)